# How to generate Digital Sine Wave?

Tags: discrete-signals, sampling

I am trying to generate a sine wave digitally. I am using LMS7200m RF chip from Lime microsystems. I want to generate a sine wave of 100KHz. The DAC on the chip has a sampling rate of 640 MHz with 12bits resolution. How can I do it in C++ or C code reliably? The Rf chips accepts only I and Q values as inputs. I am new to digital signal processing can any one help me understand on how to generate I and Q values for the sine wave in question. Thanks.

Comment: A suggestion: try to do this using your computer's sound card and a 10 kHz frequency. You can find adaptor cables to connect your sound card's output to an oscilloscope. Once you can do this, consider moving to more advanced hardware.

Comment: I suggest calling Line Microsystems and speaking with an applications engineer. What you are doing would be very specific to working with that chip and they will be best prepared to help you. How to generate a 100 KHz sine wave from a 640 MHz clock is fairly straightforward but does not involve "I" and "Q" values. They should be able to walk you through it to get their chip working for you.